# Should I encrypt my App Engine entity keys when I export data?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am currently exporting data from App Engine (to csv files) so that a few graduate students can analyze and build models based on the data. The data that I am exporting consists of non-confidential properties and the entity keys for a few models that DO contain confidential data (email addresses, names, etc.). My goal is to produce a dataset that can be shared and analyzed publicly without exposing any private data in the other entities that I’m sharing the keys for.

I started off planning to encrpyt all the entity keys to annonymize the data, but then I realized that the unencrypted keys might not be of any value to anyone as long as my app never exposes any data based on entity keys. My app only exposes personally indentifyable data based on the id for each entity.

Is there any reason to be concerned about sharing App Engine keys for entities? Is there anything that anonymous users can do with entity keys if there aren’t any urls that return any information based on the keys?

Comment: You might want to bear in mind the lesson learned by netflix, AOL, and others: even seemingly innocent anonymized data can be used to extract PII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entitiy keys contain the name of your app, the name of the entity (and any parents) and the numeric id of your entity.

If your app does not expose the data of the referenced entity you are okay.

Here`s the link in the google docs: 
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html

And more concrete docs on db.Key(): http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html

"Note: A string-encoded key can be converted back to the raw key data. This makes it easy to guess other keys when one is known. While string-encoded key values are safe to include in URLs, an application should only do so if key guessability is not an issue."

Comment: If your entity has a key name, the key will include that instead of the numeric ID. It's possible to encode confidential information into a key name, too.